# How to exclude git-untracked files with setup.py sdist

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

I am trying to release a package which is tracked by git, and I assumed setuptools would help me  with that. But if I run

`python3 sdist`

I can see that it also copies untracked files (files that I have not added to git) from the package into the archive (which are temp-scripts I use for testing but are not needed for the package itself). Can I somehow ignore them, as I don't want to always remove them before packaging?

I use `packages=find_packages()` in the `setup()` and apart from packing too many files, everything seems to be working fine.

An hour of googling did only reveal a lot of people trying to exclude certain folders/packages.. which is not what I want.
And I don't want to specify these files manually.
I just want to say "please only pack git-versioned files, thank you".

Thanks for any help!

Cheers,
Joschua

Edit: Changed the title to make clear, that I did not expect this to be default behavior.

Comment: To my knowledge, Python's packaging mechanism simply has nothing to do with Git, and therefore nothing to do with which files Git is tracking and which it isn't.  Git is simply why some of the files are there after a "git clone", and why they change when you do a "git pull".  The rest is up to the packaging system itself.

Comment: IMO, relying on Git in this way is the wrong approach. Your project's structure and textual descriptions should determine what exists in your package, not which of those files are original source files and which are not.  In general, "files in git" != "files in my package".  Files in your package might be generated from your sources instead of being source files themselves.  You might want to check files into git that you don't want in your package, like a private README containing personal notes about your project.  The two file lists are in general unrelated, and IMO, should stay that way.

Comment: `git stash --include-untracked && python setup.py sdist && git stash pop`

Comment: @Steve Thank you for your opinion, and I understand git and packaging are two different things, I just expected this "problem" to come up more often and was shocked that there was no solution to it.
Also true, that there might be files in git that should not be in the package... but I assume these can be easily excluded e.g. via the MANIFEST.in .

Comment: @hoefling Thank you very much! That helps a lot. But just for safety reasons I will do it now kind of the other way around: I'll package from a new (clean) clone of the repo. I would have expected to avoid it, but as Steve has pointed out, my approach might be governed by a wrong philosophy in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

setuptools is a python package. git is a completely separate software package for version control. The two don't even know about each other. However...

There is a [setuptools-git](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools-git/) package in PyPi that might help you do what you want to do:

Comment: NIce find.  This could very well fix the OPs problem.

Comment: I'm afraid it does not. I have experimented with setuptools-git before, and it does not seem to make a difference (maybe outdated, as it is not maintained anymore?)

Comment: late here, but - I've been using setuptools-git for years and it's always worked fine for me, and does exactly what the OP wanted. I've no idea why it didn't work when he tried it, but it certainly works for me, it includes things that are tracked by git in the distribution and excludes things that aren't.